# Trying to load my html file using nodejs to create login page

Tags: html, node.js

I am trying to use node.js to run a html file. I already have a login.html and styles.css for for the login page but now I don't know how to use the node js file to run my login.html page. I follow this [youtube](https://youtu.be/2jqok-WgelI) tutorial to make the a login authentication. It seems to have everything needed but now I dont know how to use it in my login.html file.

I need help modifying this so that I can run my login.html file.

index.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const postRoute = require('./routes/posts');

//Import Routes
const authRoute = require('./routes/auth');

dotenv.config();
//Connect to DB
mongoose.connect(
    process.env.DB_CONNECTION,
    { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true },
    () => console.log('Connected to DB')
);

//Middleware
app.use(express.json());

//Routes Middlewares
app.use('/api/user', authRoute);
app.use('/api/posts', postRoute);

// start listening
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server up and running port:3000'));
```

I am new to node.js and am completely lost on how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can solve it in two ways, first you can install view engine like ejs and use res.render (if you want more about it i can explain)

Second you can response with the HTML file like this: (works only with express and you have express)

```
app.get('/yourRotue', function(req, res, next){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/yourPath/htmlFile.html');
});
```

---

How to use EJS (basic):
First please install EJS with `npm install ejs` install body parser `npm install body-parser`
now you need to create two folders on the root folder, public and views.
inside views you can create a folder auth and put your EJS files there.
then on your app.js (or index.js, the main file) add view engine middleware:

(*notice that you dont need to require ejs, also notice you dont need to install path its built in with node)

```
//import body parser on top (to parse json/urlencoded/text..
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
//import path so you can use it for the public folder
const path = require('path');

//this line makes public folder public so you can store js/css/image...
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//use the body parser as middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '200mb' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.text({ limit: '200mb' }));

//this line tells node js to use ejs
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
//this line make sure that the views folder is the folder with the ejs files
app.set('views', 'views');

//now your route will look like this:
app.get(/routeName, (req,res,next) => {
  let example
  //you return response with render, to render the file you want.
  // you dont write the views folder name, only the file name without .ejs
  // elso you can run functions here and later send the response to the front end
  function(){
   example = 1 + 1 * 5
  }
  // *very often the function above is to find something in the db
  return res.render('auth/ejsFileName', {
        pageTitle: 'some page title for the example',
        exampleKey: example
  })
})
```

I can suggest you to use mvc (models, views, controllers) structor, if you want to know more about it you can open new question or to search about it.

EJS:

put your css and js in public folder, you can create js folder and css folder inside the public folder and then put the css in js in their folder.

*notice you dont need to write ./public in the route.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/someCssFile.css">
    <!-- here is the title that comes from the back end -->
    <title><%= pageTitle %></title>
</head>
<main>
 <h1>Here you can see the example with the function<%= exampleKey %></h1>
</main>

<script src="/js/someJsFile.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

the file look like html but it has .ejs
there is many things you can do with ejs like to loop through values.. i would suggest to learn a bit more.
this is the basic it should work.

For the post request i need to know if you are posting a form as urlEncoded or json. so i can show you how it should look like.

Comment: I managed to get my login.html running but with no css. I think I am going to go the ejs route though. My team agrees that it will be easier if we use EJS templates. I do Have a question about EJS though. Can I use my .css style for my pages? How would I go about doing this

Comment: yes you can  i will edit my answer to show you how.by the way to show your css in the html please make sure you imported the css with <link> in the head tag .

Comment: if you found this answer helpful please mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use some template engines like Handlebars. https://youtu.be/1srD3Mdvf50 You can try to follow this tutorial in order to load some html from the server side. Then you can use different selectors in order to interact with DOM elementa